# Can only one IServiceProvider be used across multiple controllers(i.e for both REST and Grpc APi controller) for a .net core web application.?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
GRPC API : 


internal class XYZ: Baseclass(Base class for Server-side implementation of Proto file)
  {
    private IServiceProvider _provider;
    public XYZ( IServiceProvider provider)
    {
     _provider = provider;
    }
  }
```

Similarly for Rest api's :

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ABC : ControllerBase
{
   public ABC(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
        }
}
```

Iam defining the ServiceProvider in startup file within Configure method.

```
    var collection = new ServiceCollection();
        collection.AddSingleton<TService, Implementation>();
        var provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
 Server server = new Server
            {
                Services = { Proto.BindService(new XYZ(provider)) },
                Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
            };
```

So when i run the project, Iam able to use my service in grpc controller class (XYZ) where as same returns exception in case of Rest Api Constructor .
Exception is : " No service for type TService has been registered". So is there a way to use the provider in both the constructors.?

Comment: Can it be that there are two interfaces `IServiceProvider` that reside in different namespaces? You can check by moving the mouse over `IServiceProvider` in ABC and XYZ.

Comment: They are under the the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you incorrect set a value to the constructor. You shouldn't send provider. You need to put your service. `Services = { Proto.BindService(new XYZ(provider.GetService(TService) )) },` Because your class shout depend on TService not on ServiceProvider.

You can take a look is it configured correctly just before create a Server get an instance of TService call `provider.GetService(TService)`.

I've created a test and all works:

```
public interface ITn
{        
}
public class In : Tn
{
}
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       var collection = new ServiceCollection();
       collection.AddSingleton<ITn, Tn>();
       var prov = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
       var tn = prov.GetService(typeof(ITn));
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue. It resolves the service in GRPC constructor but an exception in case of REST Api constructor.